# Extend and Overload MS and Point Types

Tags: math, c#-4.0, overloading, extend

Do I have make my own Point and Vector types to overload them ? Why does this not work ?

```
namespace System . windows
{
public partial struct Point : IFormattable
{
    public static Point operator * ( Point P , double D )
    {
        Point Po = new Point ( );
        return Po;
    }
}
}

namespace SilverlightApplication36
{
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{

    public static void ShrinkingRectangle ( WriteableBitmap wBM , int x1 , int y1 , int x2 , int y2 , Color C )
    {
        wBM . DrawRectangle ( x1 , y1 , x2 , y2 , Colors . Red );
        Point Center = Mean ( x1 , y1 , x2 , y2 );
        wBM . SetPixel ( Center , Colors.Blue , 3 );
        Point P1 = new Point ( x1 , y1 );
        Point P2 = new Point ( x1 , y2 );
        Point P3 = new Point ( x1 , y2 );
        Point P4 = new Point ( x2 , y1 );
        const int Steps = 10;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < Steps ; i++ )
        {
            double iF = (double)(i+1) / (double)Steps;
            double jF = ( 1.0 - iF );
            Point P11 = **P1 * jF;**
        }
    }
```

Comment: *What*, specifically, "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve with this line:

```
Point P11 = **P1 * jF;**
```

If you try to power it then use the [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) function.

**Update** 
You should have an internal field in the structure that represents your values, then implementing the operator is very easy.

As for the `IFormattable`, I didn't really test what I am writing, I just copied the code from [here](http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2005/02/24/overriding-system-object-tostring-and-implementing-iformattable/) to give you the idea:

```
public partial struct Point : IFormattable
{
  private double x;
  public double X
  {
    get { return x; }
  }

  private double y;
  public double Y
  {
    get { return y; }
  }

  public static Point operator *(Point point, double value)
  {
    return new Point(point.X * value, point.y * value);
  }

  public Point(double x, double y)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  #region IFormattable Members

  public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
  {
    if (format == null) format = "H"; //hyphenized


    if (formatProvider != null)
    {
      ICustomFormatter formatter = 
        (ICustomFormatter)formatProvider.GetFormat(this.GetType());

      if (formatter != null)
        return formatter.Format(format, this, formatProvider);
    }

    switch (format)
    {
      case "X:
        return string.Format("{0}x{1}", X, Y);
      case "C":
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}", X, Y);
      case "H":
      default:
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", X, Y); 
    }                                          
  }

  #endregion
}
```

Comment: I suspect that is meant to be just bold highlighting to show the key line in his code... I may be wrong though. I did have the same WTF thought at first too. :)

Comment: **precisely** still tinkering. hey, exactly i put star star name star star ** exactly  **

Comment: OK, so what about your question? is it solved? please don't forget to vote / mark as answer if it did.